# How to change between date formats

Tags: excel, date

How to alter this format `1-Jul-03` into `20030701`, i.e. most left 4 digits represent year, then 2 digits as month, then 2 as date.

Answer (score 3):

If cell A1 contains the date then use

`=TEXT(A1,"YYYYMMDD")`

as the formula in another cell.

If you want to use that format directly on a cell, then right click on it, choose "Format Cells", select "Custom", and enter YYYYMMDD in the Type: box.

Comment: Done. Thanks. so nice of you :)